# How to select row and column name where field is null?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I wanted to show row and column where field is null.

i already see this example  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079037/how-to-count-in-sql-all-fields-with-null-values-in-one-record)

but i don't understand xml code.

my code is like this

```
if exists (select * from Header where  [name] is Null or [zip] is Null or [age] is Null or [city] is Null )    
    begin
        declare @error1 as varchar (50) 
    select @error1=[id] from Header  where  [name] is Null or [zip] is Null or [age] is Null or [city] is Null  

        declare @error2 AS varchar(50) 

    DECLARE ocur CURSOR FOR 
    select [id] from Header where  [name] is Null or [zip] is Null or [age] is Null or [city] is Null 

    OPEN ocur

    FETCH NEXT FROM ocur 
    INTO @error1

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

    BEGIN
        --set @error2 = @error2 + @error1 + ', '
        set @error2 = 'error -' + @error1 

        insert into yan values(@error2,@uploads, GETDATE() )


        FETCH NEXT FROM ocur INTO @error1
    END

        --insert into table_error values(@error2,@uploads, GETDATE() )
    CLOSE ocur
    DEALLOCATE ocur


    end
else
    begin   
            insert code
            end
```

so i just need row code that show where column is null.

Thanks

Comment: You should learn to avoid cursors. Tbhey are huge SQL antipattern. Learn to use set-based techniques (which are usually more consise as well and easier to maintain). This should help you get started: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Cursors_and_How_to_Avoid_Them

Answer (score 1):

there is no need for using slow cursors ...

```
Insert into table_error
select 'error - ' + Cast(ID as Varchar(20)), @uploads, GetDate() 
from Header 
where  [name] is Null or [zip] is Null or [age] is Null or [city] is Null
```

Comment: WHERE condition could be written shorter:-) 

[name]+[zip]+ cast([age] as varchar)+[city] is Null

Comment: @msi77 this would be AND not OR

Comment: thanks for answering but i need column and row so the error massage can be specific

Comment: @bummy, Concatenation will be NULL, if any column is NULL. This is OR, isn't it?

Comment: @msi77 sorry, of course, usually you are right   
Declare @a Varchar(10)
Declare @b Varchar(10)

Select @a ='Test'

SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL  OFF
Select @a+@b
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL  ON
Select @a+@b

Answer (score 0):

Without XML (hardcoded)

```
declare @Header table (id int,name varchar(30),zip varchar(10),age int, city varchar(30))
insert into @Header Values(1,'Test','123',21,null);
insert into @Header Values(2,NULL,'123',21,null);
insert into @Header Values(3,NULL,NULL,21,null);
insert into @Header Values(4,'Test','123',21,null);
insert into @Header Values(5,'Test',NULL,21,null);
Select ID
, Case when Name is null then 1 else 0 end
+ Case when zip is null then 1 else 0 end
+ Case when age is null then 1 else 0 end
+ Case when City is null then 1 else 0 end 
as cnt

from @Header
```

with the output

```
id     cnt
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   1
5   2
```